# Pandas: is there an easy way to do a "replacena" style left merge?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [1, 2, np.nan, 4], 'c': [1,2,3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 3, 5], 'b': [2, 3, 5], 'c': [100, 101, 5]})
```

By "replacena" style merge, what I mean is something like

```
df_new = replacena_left_merge(df, df2, 'a')
```

where

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b': [1,2,3,4], 'c': [1,2,3,4]})
```

Written out, I want:

- A left join
- New columns in the right dataframe (as in a usual merge)
- **Duplicate columns in the right dataframe will be used to fill NaNs in the left dataframe**
- Duplicate columns in the right dataframe do will not create new columns in the result

Is there a way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fillna`:

```
df = df.set_index('a').fillna(df2.set_index('a')).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   a    b  c
0  1  1.0  1
1  2  2.0  2
2  3  3.0  3
3  4  4.0  4
```

Comment: This does not address `New columns in the right dataframe (as in a usual merge)` but I can follow it up with a normal left join. Going with this solution. Did not know about this behavior of fillna.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html). This will add all index values from left and right, so I use `loc[df.a]` to filter to only original left values.

```
df = (df.set_index('a')
      .combine_first(df2.set_index('a'))
      .loc[df.a]
      .reset_index())
```